# Image not loading from URL in Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I can't understood why these links don't open in Picasso.

http://tafsir-lib-api.rawafedtech.info/uploads/book/images/08.jpg

http://tafsir-lib-api.rawafedtech.info/uploads/book/images/06.jpg

The other image on the same server opens correctly.

This is my code:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
      .load(book.getImageUrl())
      .resize(coverWidth, coverHeight)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
      .into(viewHolder.ivBookPic);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this inside an Adapter (for example, recyclerview custom adapter), try to use the passed context.

```
Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

/* other part of the Adapter codes */

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyCustomViewHolder holder, int position){
    Picasso.with(context)
      .load(book.getImageUrl())
      .resize(coverWidth, coverHeight)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
      .into(viewHolder.ivBookPic);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Can you please post your full adapter code?